# AngularJS controller's variable is not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I have problem with below code. I have `prices` factory which returns object containing prices received from server by websocket. Prices are sent after button `Create` is clicked. Problem is that `main.prices` variable is not updated at all. I can check everything by `Check` button, which confirms this. `Prices.data` is updated, but `this.prices` is not, but it refers the same object, so I thought it should be updated as well. Do you have any ideas why below does not work as expected?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngWebSocket'])

    .factory('ws', ['$websocket', function($websocket){
        var url = 'ws://localhost/websocket';
        var ws = $websocket(url);        
        return ws;
    }])

    .factory('prices', ['ws', function(ws){
        var prices = {
            data: [],
            clear: function(){
                this.data = [];
            },
            create: function(){
                ws.send('send')
            }
        }

        ws.onMessage(function(message){
            message = JSON.parse(message.data);
            var type = message.type;

            if (type == 'new prices'){               
                prices.data = message.data;
            }
        });

        return prices;
    }])

    .controller('main', ['prices', function(prices){
        this.prices = prices.data;

        this.check = function(){
            console.log('works ', prices.data);
            console.log('not works ', this.prices);
        };

        this.create = function(){
            prices.create();
        };

        this.stop = function(){
            prices.clear();
        };
    }]);

<div ng-controller="main as main">
    {{ main.prices }}
    <button ng-click="main.create()">Create</button>
    <button ng-click="main.stop()">Stop</button>
    <button ng-click="main.check()">Check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your dealing with reference issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with the code you posted (working on a fiddle so i can help rework it) ...

First change :

```
if (type == 'new prices'){               
    prices.data = message.data;
}
```

To:

```
if (type == 'new prices'){   
    prices.data.length = 0;            
    prices.data.push.apply(prices.data,message.data) ;//copy all items to the array.
}
```

---

From a readability / maintainability point of view you should just use `this.prices` vs `this.prices.data`. It's confusing to map them to other variables, when you can just use prices.   Also note that I updated it to use "that" constantly to avoid any type of context `this` issues.

```
.controller('main', ['prices', function(prices){
    var that = this;
    that.prices = prices;

    that.check = check;
    that.create = create; 
    that.stop = stop;

    function check(){
        console.log('works ', that.prices.data);
        console.log('not works ', that.prices);
    }

    function create(){
        that.prices.create();
    }
    function stop(){
        that.prices.clear();
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I was creating new object while controller variable refered to the new one :) I needed also to change clear function to `this.data.length = 0` - the same mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous response, you also have an issue on the clear():

```
var prices = {
    ...
    clear: function(){
        this.data = [];
    },
    ...
}
```

when you do the clear with this.data = [] you are actually creating a new empty array an storing that in the this.data prop, and since this is a NEW array, the reference on main controller -> this.prices = prices.data; is still pointing to the old one. If you need to delete elements on the array just use this.data.length = 0 as Nix pointed out for the other method. that will keep all references in sync since you are re using the original array

Comment: oops, just after posting this i saw you added a comment on the other response